# Using the Forest package to root multiple nodes to a single node

Tags: forest

I want to try and route multiple nodes for example 1, 2, 3 and 4 ALL to one single node called quartile. i don't want each node going to it's own node called 'quartile'. So basically I'm trying to ask how can I route 4 nodes to a single node as opposed to what I've got below which is 4 nodes to 4 nodes. Sorry I'm new to this forum but that's the best I can explain it. Also is there a better way to do this type of diagram? would it be better to do it horizontally instead? thank you for any help.

```
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\begin{forest} for tree={%
    draw=black, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1.3cm, rounded corners=3,
    text height=1ex, text depth=0ex,
    grow=east,reversed,
    edge={black},
    parent anchor=east,
    child anchor=west,
    if n children=0{tier=last}{}
}
[data
[L2T 
    [1[quartile]][2[quartile]][3[quartile]][4[quartile]]]
[CPS 
    [1[quartile]][2[quartile]][3[quartile]][4[quartile]]]    
[HIA
    [1[quartile]][2[quartile]][3[quartile]][4[quartile]]]       
[ATT
    [1[quartile]][2[quartile]]]
]
\end{forest}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please always post complete code we can compile as it is much more useful than mere code fragments.

Comment: You seem to have 14 nodes to 14 nodes. Do you want 14 nodes to 1 node? Or do you want 14 nodes to 4 nodes?

Comment: sorry about that! I'd like 14 nodes to 4 nodes if possible, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

[image: 14 to 4]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  for tree={%
    draw,
    minimum width=1cm,
    minimum height=1.3cm,
    rounded corners=3,
  },
  before typesetting nodes={%
    where n children=0{%
      if={strequal(content(),"quartile")}{%
        delay={%
          replace by={[, phantom, tier=last, append]},
        },
        calign with current,
        for siblings/.wrap pgfmath arg={%
          tikz+={%
            \draw (.parent anchor) -- (#1.child anchor);
          }
        }{name()},
      }{%
        delay={%
          append={[, phantom, shape=coordinate, tier=last]}
        }
      }
    }{}
  },
  before packing={%
    for tree={%
      grow'=0,
      parent anchor=east,
      child anchor=west,
    }
  }
  [data
  [L2T
      [1]
      [2]
      [quartile]
      [3]
      [4]
  ]
  [CPS
      [1]
      [2]
      [quartile]
      [3]
      [4]
  ]
  [HIA
      [1]
      [2]
      [quartile]
      [3]
      [4]
  ]
  [ATT
      [1]
      [quartile]
      [2]
  ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

## EDIT

You can also join the `quartile` nodes with a final node. However, note that this is now nothing like a tree and it would probably be more easily drawn with something else. Nonetheless, if you've done this much with `forest`, you might try something like this modification:

```
\begin{forest}
  join/.style={%
    tikz+={%
      \draw [\foresteoption{edge}] (.parent anchor) -- (#1.child anchor);
    }
  },
  for tree={%
    draw,
    minimum width=1cm,
    minimum height=1.3cm,
    rounded corners=3,
  },
  before typesetting nodes={%
    where n children=0{%
      if={strequal(content(),"quartile")}{%
        append={[, phantom, tier=very last]},
        delay={%
          replace by={[, phantom, tier=last, append]},
        },
        calign with current,
        join=bl,
        for siblings/.wrap pgfmath arg={%
          append={[, phantom, shape=coordinate, tier=last]},
          join=#1,
        }{name()},
      }{%
      }
    }{}
  },
  before packing={%
    for tree={%
      grow'=0,
      parent anchor=east,
      child anchor=west,
    }
  }
  [data
    [L2T
      [1]
      [2]
      [quartile, name=q1]
      [3]
      [4]
    ]
    [CPS
      [1]
      [2]
      [quartile, name=q2]
      [3]
      [4]
    ]
    [, phantom, tier=very last, calign with current
      [beyond last, calign with current, name=bl]
    ]
    [HIA
      [1]
      [2]
      [quartile, name=q3]
      [3]
      [4]
    ]
    [ATT
      [1]
      [quartile, name=q4]
      [2]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

[image: 14 2 4 + 4 2 1]

## UPDATE

I would probably try something like this, however, as I think it makes the diagram a bit clearer:

[image: squared look]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{edges}
\begin{document}
\forestapplylibrarydefaults{edges}
\begin{forest}
  join/.style={%
    tikz+={% adapted from edges library
      \draw  (.parent anchor)  -- ++(\forestoption{fork sep},0) |- (#1.child anchor);
    }
  },
  forked edges,
  for tree={%
    draw,
    minimum width=1cm,
    minimum height=1.3cm,
    rounded corners=3,
    anchor=west,
  },
  before typesetting nodes={%
    where n children=0{%
      if={strequal(content(),"quartile")}{%
        append={[, phantom, tier=very last]},
        delay={%
          replace by={[, phantom, shape=coordinate, calign with current, append]},
        },
        calign with current,
        tier=last,
        no edge,
        anchor=west,
        join=bl,
        for siblings/.wrap pgfmath arg={%
          append={[, phantom, shape=coordinate, tier=last]},
          join=#1,
        }{name()},
      }{%
      }
    }{}
  },
  before packing={%
    for tree={%
      grow'=0,
      parent anchor=east,
      child anchor=west,
    }
  }
  [data
    [L2T
      [1]
      [2]
      [quartile, name=q1]
      [3]
      [4]
    ]
    [CPS
      [1]
      [2]
      [quartile, name=q2]
      [3]
      [4]
    ]
    [, phantom, calign with current, shape=coordinate
      [beyond last, tier=very last, calign with current, name=bl]
    ]
    [HIA
      [1]
      [2]
      [quartile, name=q3]
      [3]
      [4]
    ]
    [ATT
      [1]
      [quartile, name=q4]
      [2]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's perfect thank you! Is there anyway all four quartile nodes could now go to one end node?

Comment: As in all quartile nodes end up at a final node (i.e the opposite of the beginning of the diagram)

Comment: Please see edit and update above.